# Stepwise Cointegration

Tags: time-series, r, cointegration, manager-analysis

This is more of a general question at this point, but if my thought process makes sense I  will follow up with an R implementation. I have read a number of papers on cointegration analysis for pairs trading. My thought was to apply cointegration to an analysis of investment manager returns. Typically investment-manager returns are regressed on factor returns to estimate risk exposures and alpha (intercept). Instead, I would like to use cointegration analysis to estimate risk exposures and alpha based on the level of cumulative wealth invested in a manager's strategy vs. various risk exposures.

I am using R. My thought was to use a stepwise regression-type procedure based on AIC to find a good fit for manager returns with a parsimonious model. Basically the idea was to create a function that would step through various cointegration vectors, and arrive at the vector tested with the lowest AIC that results in stationary residuals based on an ADF test. I could then test for significant alpha using Newey-West standard errors. I have a few questions:

1. Is this a reasonable thing to do?
2. Given my knowledge of the risk exposures and investment managers, I think there exists only one cointegrating vector. Given this, does it make sense to use the Engle-Granger method?  This is much easier to work with in R for what I am trying to do.
3. If it is reasonable to use the Engle-Granger method with `lm()`, in order to estimate alpha (a positive/negative drift in level of wealth over time), can I just add a vector of lenght N to the regression, where each value is equal to t? Then the estimated weight of this term would be equal to added wealth per period not explained by risk (manager skill).

***Edit*** sample code is below.  I haven't included an algorithm to step through different
regression factors as I just included a simple equity manager, and adding and removing factors becomes more useful I think as you delve into alternatives and are looking at many more possible risk factors.

```
require(tseries)
require(sandwich)
require(lmtest)

#---------------- Data--------------------------------------------------------------

managerReturns<-ts(c(-0.008,0.022,0.061,0.013,-0.076,-0.041,0.063,-0.030,0.071
                    ,0.036,-0.010,0.055,0.018,0.039,0.002,0.036,0.003,-0.014
                    ,-0.033,-0.018,-0.055,0.069,0.004,0.019,0.028,0.018,0.028
                    ,-0.008,-0.037,0.048,0.003,0.019,0.025,-0.020,0.013,0.007),
                    start = c(2010,01),frequency=12)

mkt<-ts(c(-0.0336,0.034,0.0632,0.02,-0.0789,-0.0556,0.0692,-0.0477,0.0954,0.0388,
       0.0061,0.0682,0.0201,0.0349,0.0048,0.029,-0.0127,-0.0175,-0.0234,-0.06,
       -0.076,0.1134,-0.0026,0.0074,0.0506,0.0443,0.0311,-0.0084,-0.062,0.0388,
       0.0079,0.0256,0.0274,-0.0175,0.0077,0.0118),start = c(2010,01),frequency=12)

value<-ts(c(0.0019,0.0142,0.0157,0.0493,-0.0009,-0.0212,0.0013,-0.0289,0.0383,
         0.0103,0.0366,0.0075,-0.0246,0.0165,0.0259,-0.003,-0.0066,-0.0008,
         -0.0144,-0.0329,-0.0371,0.0357,-0.0025,-0.0055,0.0253,-0.0161,-0.0022,
         -0.0061,-0.0009,0.0083,-0.0257,0.0073,0.0045,-0.0104,0.0069,0.0165),
          start = c(2010,01),frequency=12)

size<-ts(c(0.0061,0.0273,0.0206,0.0314,-0.0234,-0.0427,0.002,-0.017,-0.0305,
        -0.0228,-0.0051,0.036,0.0084,0.0167,-0.0119,-0.0227,-0.0214,-0.0045,
        -0.0112,-0.0146,-0.0091,-0.0102,-0.001,0.0154,-0.0221,-0.0003,-0.0003,
        -0.0019,0.0017,0.0039,-0.0003,0.0056,0.0159,0.0408,-0.0112,0.0329),
         start = c(2010,01),frequency=12)

rf<-ts(c(0,0,0.0001,0,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,
      0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0,0,0,0,0.0001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0001,0,0,0.0001,
      0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001),start = c(2010,01),frequency=12)

mangerReturns<-log(managerReturns+1)
mkt<-log(mkt+1)
value<-log(value+1)
size<-log(size+1)
rf<-log(rf+1)
managerExcess<-managerReturns-rf

# ----------------------------------- Returns based Factor Analysis----------------

fit<-lm(managerExcess~mkt+value+size)
summary(fit)

# ----------------------------------- Cointegration Analysis ----------------------

lvlManager<-cumsum(managerExcess)
lvlMkt<-cumsum(mkt)
lvlValue<-cumsum(value)
lvlSize<-cumsum(size)
alpha<-seq(1,length(lvlManager))

fit2<-lm(lvlManager~lvlMkt+lvlValue+lvlSize+alpha)
#Coefficient test with Newey-West Standard Errors
coeftest(fit2,NeweyWest(fit2))
#Check for stationarity
adf.test(residuals(fit2))
```

Comment: maybe you can write down at least skeleton of some basic equation you want to test, it will be much easier to guess what you want tocompute

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Johansen-Procedure for determining the cointegration vector, the `ca.jo`-function from `library(urca)`. After determining the cointegration rank, a normalized cointegration vector is produced by estimating a restricted VECM with the command `cajorls()`.